# VC2008 Read data to stream GDI+

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2008, stream, gdi+

Code to save jpeg in disk:

```
fwrite( dataPosition, 1, BufferSize, hFileImage );
```

That code work good. 
But something is wrong when I try read data to stream:

```
HGLOBAL hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, BufferSize);
CComPtr<IStream> spStream;
HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &spStream);
ULONG pcbWritten;//don't understand what it is
spStream->Write(dataPosition, BufferSize, &pcbWritten);
pImage = new Image(spStream, FALSE);
```

After that it seems that stream (and pImage) is empty. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to rename `pcbWritten` to `cbWritten`, since `pcb​Written` means "pointer to the count of bytes written", but the variable itself isn't a pointer.

Comment: I set pcbWritten as NULL and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you wrote to the stream, you perhaps should [`IStream::Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the stream to its beginning so that following `Image` constructor could read the data, and not immediately reach end of stream instead.

```
static const ULONGLONG g_nZero = 0;
HRESULT nSeekResult = pStream->Seek(reinterpret_cast<const LARGE_INTEGER&>(g_nZero),
  STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);
```

Comment: ok i agree, but i don't  understand parametrs in this method
should i write that way: spStream->Seek(dataPosition,STREAM_SEEK_SET,&dataPosition);
because it compile fine, but gives me error during work with device